# Как удалить строку таблицы при совпадении значения tr с переменной?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте! Такая проблема: есть таблица HTML такого вида:

```js
var i = 1;

setTimeout(() => {
  $("#table2 td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('first')) {
      if ($(this).val(i)) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      }
    }
  })
}, 3333)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>not completed</td>
    <td class="first">1</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>not completed</td>
    <td class="first">2</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Существует еще переменная, которая равна 1. Нужно сравнить четвертый td, у которого задан класс, и если они совпадают, то удалить tr вместе со всем содержимым. Но проблема в том, что таблица динамическая, и самих строк может быть очень много. Для реализации написала такой код в JS:

Но удаляется абсолютно всё внутри таблицы, а должен лишь первый tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).val(i)` - этот метод не применим к объекту типа `td`, кроме того, он задает значение, а не возвращает сравнение ...

```js
var i = 1;

$('#table2 .first').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if(parseInt($this.text()) === i) $this.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>not completed</td>
    <td class="first">1</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>not completed</td>
    <td class="first">2</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```